# how to checkout latest commit of a specific remote in bash script

Tags: git, bash

I have a cloned git repository locally, and want to checkout the latest commit (of the remote *origin*), no matter what branch I've currently checked out, what branch the latest commit was in or if I ever checked out the branch of the latest commit locally.

Is there any way to get to the latest (last) origin commit independent of the local *state* with git 2.4.9 (in a bash script)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
git fetch origin
git branch --remotes                             |\
grep origin/                                     |\
grep -v origin/HEAD                              |\
xargs -n 1 git log -1 --format='format:%ct %h%n' |\
sort -n                                          |\
tail -1                                          |\
cut -d' ' -f2
```

A piece at a time:

- [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) just makes sure you're up to date.
- [`git branch --remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) lists all remote branches

  ```
  origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  origin/do_a_thing
  origin/master
  ```
- `grep origin/` picks only branches on `origin` (if you have multiple remotes)
- `grep -v origin/HEAD` removes the `origin/HEAD -> origin/master` line that will get in the way
- `xargs -n 1` passes the branch names one at a time to...
- [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log)

  - `-1` takes just the last commit on the branch
  - [`--format='format:%ct %h%n'`](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) prints the UNIX commit time (integer), SHA, and a newline

    ```
    1446771676 5cac5ed
    1443639221 001a41a
    1426461600 ac41d80
    ```
- `sort -n` by the commit time as a number
- `tail -1` the last row (latest time)
- `cut -d' ' -f2` splits on the space and pulls out the SHA

Answer (score 3):

The top line of `git log --branches` will show the latest commit from any branch.  Likewise, the top line of `git log --remotes` will show the latest commit from any remote branch.

First, make sure you're up to date with origin:

```
git fetch origin
```

I have a habit of updating all of my remotes at once, but this is not necessary:

```
git remote update
```

If you want to checkout the latest commit from any branch, you can do:

```
git checkout `git log --remotes -1 --format=%H`
```